# Rigid Body Collision Relative Velocity Calculation

Tags: java, math, vector, geometry, physics

This is my code:

```
Vec2 fv = nv.scale(-((1D + aelas) * getLinearVelocity().sub(shape.getLinearVelocity()).dot(nv)));
```

aelas is a double, set to 1D(later on I can change to a function)
nv is the unit-normal-vector

My issue is that the collision only properly reacts with perfect elasticity when aelas is 0, but when it is 1, it treats it as if the elasticity is >2D(so, more energy goes out then comes in).

My thinking is that my system for relative velocity is incorrect, causing it to improperly react.

I have thoroughly debugged my code, and am fairly certain that it is my math. Anyone care to share some insight?

Vec2 Class:

```
package JavaProphet.Profis.Geometry;

/**
 * Created by JavaProphet on 12/8/13 at 12:28 PM.
 */
public class Vec2 {
private final double x;
private final double y;
public static final Vec2 ZERO_VEC = new Vec2(0D, 0D);

/**
 * Empty Vector.
 */
public Vec2() {
    x = 0D;
    y = 0D;
}

public String toString() {
    return "<" + getX() + ", " + getY() + ">";
}

/**
 * Uses basic trigonometry to create a Vec2 from a radian.
 *
 * @param rad The radian.
 */
public Vec2(double rad) {
    x = Math.sin(rad);
    y = Math.cos(rad);
}

/**
 * Assigns a vector it's value.
 */
public Vec2(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

/**
 * Assigns a vector it's value from a double array of length 2.
 */
public Vec2(double v[]) {
    this.x = v[0];
    this.y = v[1];
}

/**
 * Assigns a vector it's value from subtraction of position.
 *
 * @param x  x1
 * @param x2 x2
 * @param y  y1
 * @param y2 y
 */
public Vec2(double x, double y, double x2, double y2) {
    this.x = x2 - x;
    this.y = y2 - y;
}

/**
 * @return The x value from the vector.
 */
public double getX() {
    return x;
}

/**
 * @return The y value from the vector.
 */
public double getY() {
    return y;
}

/**
 * Adds two vectors.
 */
public Vec2 add(Vec2 vec) {
    return new Vec2(getX() + vec.getX(), getY() + vec.getY());
}

/**
 * Subtracts two vectors.
 */
public Vec2 sub(Vec2 vec) {
    return new Vec2(getX() - vec.getX(), getY() - vec.getY());
}

/**
 * Performs a dot product on two vectors.
 */
public double dot(Vec2 vec) {
    return getX() * vec.getX() + getY() * vec.getY();
}

/**
 * Scales magnitude of a vector by a scalar.
 *
 * @param sc The scalar.
 */
public Vec2 scale(double sc) {
    return new Vec2(getX() * sc, getY() * sc);
}

/**
 * Scales magnitude of a vector by two scalars.
 *
 * @param x The x scalar.
 * @param y The y scalar.
 */
public Vec2 scale(double x, double y) {
    return new Vec2(getX() * x, getY() * y);
}

public boolean equals(Vec2 vec) {
    return vec.getX() == getX() && vec.getY() == getY();
}

public double relativeCosine(Vec2 vec) {
    double d = dot(vec);
    double rc = d / (getMagnitude() * vec.getMagnitude());
    return rc;
}

public double relativeRadian(Vec2 vec) {
    return Math.acos(relativeCosine(vec));
}

public double getRot() {
    return Math.atan2(getY(), getX());
}

/**
 * Rotates the vector around the origin.
 *
 * @param rad A radian to rotate by.
 * @return The result.
 */
public Vec2 rot(double rad) {
    double sin = Math.sin(rad);
    double cos = Math.cos(rad);
    double t1 = ((cos * getX()) - (sin * getY()));
    double t2 = ((sin * getX()) + (cos * getY()));
    return new Vec2(t1, t2);
}

/**
 * Retrieves the slope for this vector.
 *
 * @param vec A vector in which is paired to make a line segment.
 * @return A slope.
 */
public double slope(Vec2 vec) {
    return (vec.getX() - getX()) / (vec.getY() - getY());
}

/**
 * Scales magnitude of a vector to a tracable amount. (1 / x, 1 / y)
 */
public Vec2 tscale() {
    return new Vec2(1D / getX(), 1D / getY());
}

/**
 * Inverts a vector(-x, -y).
 */
public Vec2 invert() {
    return new Vec2(-getX(), -getY());
}

private double mag = 0D; // magnitude cannot be 0, so if zero, calc mag.

/**
 * Return the length, or magnitude of a vector, uses sqrt.
 */
public double getMagnitude() {
    if(mag == 0D && (getX() != 0D || getY() != 0D)) {
        mag = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(getX(), 2) + Math.pow(getY(), 2));
    }
    return mag;
}

/**
 * Converts a vector to a unit vector (x / length, y / length), uses sqrt.
 */
public Vec2 uscale() {
    double length = getMagnitude();
    return new Vec2(getX() / length, getY() / length);
}

/**
 * Converts a vector to a unit vector (x / length, y / length), uses sqrt.
 */
public Vec2 hat() {
    return uscale();
}
}
```

Comment: Split up the calculation into multiple lines, print out each line, and verify the output

Comment: Yes (as vandale says), my physics has become rusty but isn't the real problem that getLinearVelocity().sub(shape.getLinearVelocity()).dot(nv))) is greater than 1, and it shouldn't be.  Can you post getLinearVelocity?

Comment: @JimW Here is the output I made: 
    
    getLinearVelocity().sub(shape.getLinearVelocity()).dot(nv)) = 2.0
    getLinearVelocity().sub(shape.getLinearVelocity()) = <0.0, 2.0>
    getLinearVelocity() = <0.0, 1.0>
    shape.getLinearVelocity() = <0.0, -1.0>
    nv = <0.0, 1.0>
    fv = <-0.0, -4.0>

Comment: Can you add your other methods to the post so we can see them?  I was wrong dot product can be >1.

Comment: @JimW I added the Vec2 class.

Answer (score 0):

For rigid body physics, this code line is entirely correct IF *fv* is going to be **added** to the existing velocity of *this*, and the *shape* is an infinite mass boundary.
If your other code is trying to use fv as 'final velocity', it shouldn't have the constant 1 in it's calculation (and is simply wrong in oblique collisions anyway).

For extension to finite mass pair collisions the 1D constant turns into a signed weighting function, which I'll leave as an exercise for the reader.